# asp.net mvc3, why my dropdownlist is not selected?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, drop-down-menu, html.dropdownlistfor

I create my selectlist from enum.

```
[Flags]
public enum Age
{
    New_Born = 1,
    Toddler = 2,
    Preschool = 4,
    Kindergarten = 8,
    Elementary_School = 16,
    Middle_School = 32,
    High_School = 64
}


var age = from Age e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Age))
          select new { Id = (int)e, Name = e.ToString().Replace("_", " ") };
```

I tried both:

```
var ageList = new SelectList(age, "Id", "Name", (int)Model.Child.Age);
```

or

```
var ageList = new SelectList(age, "Id", "Name", Model.Child.Age);


@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Child.Age, ageList, "Your Child's Age")
```

Everything works except the selected value didn't get selected.

**EDIT: after hours testing, finally fix it.**
chagne Id = (int)e to Id = e.

```
var age = from Age e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Age))
          select new { Id = e, Name = e.ToString().Replace("_", " ") };
```

var ageList = new SelectList(age, "Id", "Name", Model.Child.Age);

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is the `Age` enum defined as a `Flags` enum? You expect a child to be able to be in both `Toddler` and `Preschool` (for example)?

Comment: we recommend book and app for kids,  some books can be good for both middle and high school kids.

Comment: I assume your Model.Child.Age has some value, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**after hours testing, finally fix it. chagne Id = (int)e to Id = e.**

var age = from Age e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Age))
          select new { Id = e, Name = e.ToString().Replace("_", " ") };

var ageList = new SelectList(age, "Id", "Name", Model.Child.Age);

Answer (score 0):

I just created a similar example and worked out your problem and I believe you have two problems with your code:

In your controller code, you should have your first option, like this:

```
SelectList selectList = new SelectList(items, "Id", "Name", (int)Qualities.Whatever);
```

And in your view:

```
<%= this.Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.List.SelectedValue, this.Model.List, "Qualities") %>
```

Think about it, why would you pass the SelectList twice? You should pass the selected value and then the list of values.

The fact that I didn't use Razor view engine is irrelevant.

Comment: thanks for your help, that didnt fix it.  but I manage to get it fixed. all i have to do is to remove (int)

Comment: I find it strange. But anyway, can you please answer your own question with your code and mark it as correct? That will help me see another way to fix the issue and other people too who come up with it.